# php - get sum of clicks for past 7 days

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table `xeon_users_rented`, with: `clicks0`, `clicks1`, `clicks2`, `clicks3`, `clicks4`, `clicks5`, `clicks6`

Each day, `clicks0` will increase, and every day at midnight, a cronjob will run, making `clicks0 = clicks1` (setting todays clicks, to yesterday clicks), and then set `clicks0` to zero.

**What I am trying to achieve is** I want to make a graph, that shows the sum of clicks0, clicks1 etc., where clicks0 is todays date.

I have the query below:

```
$data = array();
for ($x = 0; $x <= 6; $x++) {
    $date = date("Y/m/d", time() - ($x * 86400));
    $queryE = $dbh->prepare("SELECT SUM(clicks$x) FROM xeon_users_rented WHERE user_by=:username");
    $queryE->bindParam(":username", $userdata['username']);
    $queryE->execute();
    $row = $queryE->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $dates[] = date("Y/m/d", time() - ($x * 86400));   
    $data[] = ($row['clicks'.$x.''] > 0 ? $row['clicks'.$x.''] : 0);
}
$days = array('Today');
for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $days[$i] = date('d-m', strtotime('-'.($i + 0).' day'));
}
```

The `$days` is working perfectly - it will print out today, and the last couple of days.

The **$data** is not working. It is just printing out:

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Can someone please help me out here.

Comment: Have you gone through the code with a fine toothpick and `var_dump()`ed everything that may be causing this? That is what people do when debugging code; you should learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column from your SUM isn't going to be named clicks$x.  It will be named something like SUM(clicks1).

Provide an explicit name in the SQL, like

```
SELECT SUM(clicks$x) as clickSum ...
```

Then reference it in row as

```
$row['clickSum']
```